# SignalR weird reconnect pattern

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm working with SignalR under very specific set of network conditions (a crazy proxy). So sockets do not work at all and I have to use long-polling. When I refresh a page it seems to work for a while but then the first Disconnect happens. I'm trying to automatically reconnect on disconnected event and the following pattern:

1. After the page is loaded, hub disconnects in about 110 seconds (default timeout)
2. It takes 3 Disconnected events to restart a hub after the first disconnect (so it connects only on the 4th try)
3. After that it always reconnects on the 1st try but disconnects after about 10-15 seconds (not 110 seconds). So it looks like keep-alive timeout is somehow involed here (while it wasn't on the first try).

This behaviour seems weird. Is there anything I can do to improve it?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your network conditions?

Comment: @BrendanGreen, it is a corporate network with some proxy (Webwasher) and a lot of things being blocked (it's a German corporate network, you know...)

Comment: @BrendanGreen, have you seen the page at http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events ? The connection behaviour for SignalR is 'undefined', you can observe many disconnects and reconnects in a short time frame without an apparent reason. The page gives guidelines on how to change the behaviour as well, for instance setting `GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(110);`

Comment: @gd73, sure I checked it out but did not find anything about the pattern described in the question. Now I think may be this pattern is specific to a proxy I deal with.

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back. The browser (I forget which was which now) did not support the sockets properly and had to be changed to long polling. Try on a different browser and see if you get the same results.

Comment: You should enable SignalR tracing to see what is going on there. Take a look here how to do it: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing

Answer (score 2):

Assume the tips available in [Understanding and Handling Connection Lifetime Events in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events) where you can employ good solutions to handle connection lifetime based on the network problem. Furthermore, In SignalR's issues I found the following solution for you which works with long-polling too.

You can set the `KeepAlive` property on the `ConfigurationManager` and SignalR will send an empty frame of data (based on the transport) on the specified interval to keep the connection alive (look at [Allow host to specify keep alive times](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/commit/832383d8b2c2f7cbde71f5ff73c6a5382582fe2f)). The current time-out mechanism makes the streaming protocols no different.

Comment: Seems like KeepAlive is enabled by default

Comment: @Idsa For transports other than long polling, send a `keepalive` packet every 10 seconds. This value must be no more than 1/3 of the `DisconnectTimeout` value.

Answer (score 2):

Use ConnectionStatusStream. This stream OnNexts when the client side SignalR hub proxy events are raised. So we see thing like Connecting, Connected,ConnectionSlow, Reconnecting,Reconnected,Closed,Uninitialized. All of which started out life as events on the SignalR hub proxy, and are turned in to an IObservable stream using one of the many RX factories. In this case IObservable.FromEvent.

Anyway here is the overall ConnectivityStatusViewModel that we use to show the information in the bottom status bar of the app.

Refer this:

[ConnectionStatusStream](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/851437/SignalR-plus-RX-Streaming-Data-Demo-App-of)

Comment: I've looked through the code. While it's a nice architecture (never worked with RX though) I don't see how it solves the problem I described